# Scrolling edge effect on a RecyclerView on Lollipop doesn't follow the finger

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-scrollview

I got lollipop recently and tested my app on it, but the scrolling edge effect is not like on google apps for instance. What I mean by it doesn't follow the finger is that when you overscroll bottom on the left side of the screen for instance, the scrolling edge effect will be larger on the left than on the right, it will be somehow oriented on the left.

[image: on my app (right) the scrolling effect is not oriented on the left]

As you can see, on my app (on the right) the scrolling edge effect is not oriented left. I have used the `RecyclerView` from the app compatibility library for the list. Does anyone have an idea why it is not behaving as supposed ?

Comment: From what I've seen this only happens with RecyclerViews. I experience correct behavior in other lists.

Comment: That would be very weird as the `RecyclerView` is meant to replace the old `ListView`. I will look into that but replacing my RecyclerView with an other list view is definitely not a solution for me.

Comment: It's a bug in RecyclerView. We'll fix it in a future release. I do not think there is a simple workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the precision alanv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to alanv in the comments of my post, this is a bug of the `RecyclerView`, so there is nothing to be done to fix it appart from waiting for the android team to fix the bug.